# Sign WCF message with certificate

Tags: wcf, certificate, sign

I am trying to call a third party service. I need to sign my messages with a certificate.

I checked the connectivity using SOAPUI and it works fine. I am now trying to make the call from a WCF client but cannot make it work.
I'm not familiar with this and may have missed an obvious step.

The configuration generated by svcutil looked like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ServiceBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://url.com" binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="ServiceBinding" contract="ServiceContract"
          name="Name" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I added an endpointBehaviour to get the certificate from the store. I also had to change the binding configuration because the signature was not added to the message; I changed the security mode to `TransportWithMessageCredentials` and set the client credential type of the message to `Certificate`.
The modified configuration looks like this (I removed the parts that are not relevant):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ServiceBinding">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://url.com" behaviorConfiguration="Behavior"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServiceBinding"
        contract="ServiceContract" name="Name" />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Behavior">
          <clientCredentials>
            <clientCertificate storeName="My" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" findValue="..."/>
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

When I try to make a call, I'm getting the following error:

> Security processor was unable to find a security header in the
>   message. This might be because the message is an unsecured fault or
>   because there is a binding mismatch between the communicating parties.
>   This can occur if the service is configured for security and the
>   client is not using security.

I found a few posts regarding this error but none of them could help me.
I added `ProtectionLevel=System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.Sign`
to the ServiceContractAttribute as seen in [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/667b3e8a-562f-466f-a992-18fdcca3c5ec/wcf-security-processor-was-unable-to-find-a-security-header-in-the-message?forum=wcf).

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

EDIT:

Upon inspecting the trace logs, I see that the message is sent and that I receive a meaningful response. However, there is no header in the response (which I assume causes the exception). Is there a way I can configure my client to *not* check for a header in the response?

Trace of request:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
  <System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
    <EventID>0</EventID>
    <Type>3</Type>
    <SubType Name="Information">0</SubType>
    <Level>8</Level>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-04-21T09:41:19.9227910Z"/>
    <Source Name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging"/>
    <Correlation ActivityID="{ba5c25df-1f0a-4375-8b15-e2160e21bc14}"/>
    <Execution ProcessName="w3wp" ProcessID="8540" ThreadID="16"/>
    <Channel/>
    <Computer>PC673</Computer>
  </System>
  <ApplicationData>
    <TraceData>
      <DataItem>
        <MessageLogTraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/ServiceModel/Management/MessageTrace" Time="2015-04-21T11:41:19.9217909+02:00" Source="TransportSend" Type="System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAppliedMessage">
          <Addressing>
            <Action/>
            <To>https://url.com</To>
          </Addressing>
          <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <s:Header>
              <o:Security xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" s:mustUnderstand="1">
                <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
                  <u:Created>2015-04-21T09:41:08.287Z</u:Created>
                  <u:Expires>2015-04-21T09:46:08.287Z</u:Expires>
                </u:Timestamp>
                <o:BinarySecurityToken>
                  <!-- Removed-->
                </o:BinarySecurityToken>
                <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                  <SignedInfo>
                    <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                    <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
                    <Reference URI="#_0">
                      <Transforms>
                        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                      </Transforms>
                      <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                      <DigestValue>zvttNRawVVcleH5WAYMCi7oBzpM=</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                  </SignedInfo>
                  <SignatureValue>iEMTR/xKruW1TeqJiPdXjNKG3D4ZWyfFM3T+iPy8NSCpwQIpwXmsmrOjT2N5QJoG7S+wyIm2Vsa4rmlmyYBM18rNMeN+luHuUYvNh9ammWyYgam5/mpGBmR8KJiyPSiCxCPeUWuL8z5ag2wGtTrTH/JqOsHfdobnhznvQJgPAc8YWAk6On7SkHT+nKikGv1rEfbCtOBeggbBLLzSArVOBDDOZhWRpRJLhvU6XhlYj1IbgMy4tFP8f0+SESU/UQM+0bBnt0IDwwtTQIyeheifVJINeUHe+T1Pr8qYtyo9/sLulr1vkFe0DAokv1R1WRCU5IoE38I/ptILOMvIq1s3OQ==</SignatureValue>
                  <KeyInfo>
                    <o:SecurityTokenReference>
                      <o:Reference ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" URI="#uuid-bda377d4-237a-46b7-a7c3-b7d47578c278-1"/>
                    </o:SecurityTokenReference>
                  </KeyInfo>
                </Signature>
              </o:Security>
            </s:Header>
            <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
              <!-- Valid request -->
            </s:Body>
          </s:Envelope>
        </MessageLogTraceRecord>
      </DataItem>
    </TraceData>
  </ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
```

Trace of response:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
  <System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
    <EventID>0</EventID>
    <Type>3</Type>
    <SubType Name="Information">0</SubType>
    <Level>8</Level>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-04-21T09:41:22.4049329Z"/>
    <Source Name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging"/>
    <Correlation ActivityID="{ba5c25df-1f0a-4375-8b15-e2160e21bc14}"/>
    <Execution ProcessName="w3wp" ProcessID="8540" ThreadID="16"/>
    <Channel/>
    <Computer>PC673</Computer>
  </System>
  <ApplicationData>
    <TraceData>
      <DataItem>
        <MessageLogTraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/ServiceModel/Management/MessageTrace" Time="2015-04-21T11:41:22.4049329+02:00" Source="TransportReceive" Type="System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessage">
          <HttpResponse>
            <StatusCode>OK</StatusCode>
            <StatusDescription>OK</StatusDescription>
            <WebHeaders>
              <X-Backside-Transport>OK OK</X-Backside-Transport>
              <Connection>Keep-Alive</Connection>
              <Transfer-Encoding>chunked</Transfer-Encoding>
              <X-Client-IP>194.78.45.187</X-Client-IP>
              <Content-Type>text/xml</Content-Type>
              <Date>Tue, 21 Apr 2015 09:41:11 GMT</Date>
              <Server>Apache-Coyote/1.1</Server>
            </WebHeaders>
          </HttpResponse>
          <Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <s:Header xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
            <Body>
              <!-- Meaningful response - the same I get when using SOAPUI -->
            </Body>
          </Envelope>
        </MessageLogTraceRecord>
      </DataItem>
    </TraceData>
  </ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the issue by creating a custom binding.

```
<binding name="ServiceBinding">
  <security authenticationMode="CertificateOverTransport"
    messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10"
    requireDerivedKeys="false"
    securityHeaderLayout="Lax"
    enableUnsecuredResponse="true" />
  <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
  <httpsTransport />
</binding>
```

The key here is the `enableUnsecuredResponse="true"`. This way, I can receive unsigned response without crashing.

Answer (score 1):

the bindings in wcf must be the same on client and server side. If you set the securitymode to transport, the message it self will not be encrypted. It is only a secure tunnel.
So set the securitymode to message and the protectionlevel to encrypt and sign.

Here is a good overview of the encryption options:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650862.aspx

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I tried to change the security mode to `Message` but I'm getting another error when opening the client: An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'.
I've tried to use a wsHttpBinding hoping it would work but I get the same error. I did some research on the topic but couldn't find any think helpful.

Comment: if you use the securitytye message, you dont need a https binding, because the message itself is encrypted... try it with basicHttpBinding. Or is ssl needed?

Comment: Can you please post the new xml files?

Comment: I don't use https binding, it is the uri of the service. <endpoint address="**https**://url.com" behaviorConfiguration="Behavior" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServiceBinding" contract="ServiceContract" name="Name" />
The only thing I changed in the configuration is <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ServiceBinding">
          <security mode="**Message**">
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>

Comment: Also, I think I don't need to encrypt the message, only sign it with the certificate.

Comment: Yes thats what i asked in my first commet :-) Ok that will be a hard way. First is to set the securitymode of both communication-partners to the same type: transport or message. I think its not possible to sign a message while transportsecurity is set. Further it can only be: no encryption, encryt; encrypt and sign... So I guess you have to encrypt the message. I guess wcf has a problem with a http-binding on a https service-url